# simplify freeing many pointers using macro

Tags: c, free

how simplify freeing many pointer in this c code using macro :

```
void main() {
    char *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;

    a = strdup ("test1");
    b = strdup ("test2");  
    c = strdup ("test3"); 
    d = strdup ("test4"); 
    e = strdup ("test5"); 
    f = strdup ("test6"); 

     strcpy(a, "");
     strcpy(e, "");
     strcpy(f, "");


    if(!strcmp(a, "")) 
       free(a);
    if!strcmp(b, ""))
       free(b);
    if(!strcmp(c, ""))
       free(c);
    if(!strcmp(d, ""))
       free(d);
    if(!strcmp(e, ""))
       free(e);
    if(!strcmp(f, ""))
       free(f);
}
```

Comment: This edit changes a lot of things.

Comment: So, which of these you would like to free? All or which are NOT having "" values? or which are having ""?

Comment: @Digital_Reality  : which are having ""

Comment: @Digital_Reality : the goal of this question is to simplify freeing many pointer using macro

Comment: You will get ideas on simplification, but just make pointers NULL after freeing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is broken, the comparisons against `""` make no sense.

You should just `free()` all of them; if any allocation failed the pointer will be `NULL` but passing `NULL` to `free()` is fine. There is no need to check at the application level.

I assume that your code is some kind of fragment meant to illustrate a point, rather than actual code. If so, then of course you should remove the whole `strdup()`/`free()` dance and just use constant strings:

```
const char *a = "test1", *b = "test2" /* and so on */;
```

**UPDATE** After the question has been edited, it makes even less sense to me. It's *not* a good idea to ever `strcpy()` into a string returned by `strdup()`, since you don't know the length of the buffer there's no way to make the copy safe. Also, even if you do overwrite the string with an empty string, you *still* (of course) own the memory and should call `free()` on it.

That said, perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
#define MAYBE_FREE(s)    do { if(s != NULL && s[0] != '\0') free(s); } while(0)
```

The wrapping in a `do/while` loop makes the macro behave as a statement, so you can do:

```
MAYBE_FREE(a);
if(something())
  MAYBE_FREE(b);
```

and so on.

Comment: I'd add a note, that if the OP really wants to compare the strings against empty ones, they should use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: the goal of this question is to simplify freeing many pointer using macro